# Integrating a function of itself?

Tags: calculus, general-relativity

In physics, the radial velocity of a particle around a black hole is given by this equation:

$$ \left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2 = \left({E\over m}\right)^2 - \left(1-{2M\over r}\right)\left(1+ \left({l\over r}\right)^2\right) $$

which can be rewritten as

$$ dr = \sqrt{\left({E\over m}\right)^2 - \left(1-{2M\over r}\right)\left(1+ \left({l\over r}\right)^2\right)}\space\space d\tau $$

So

$$ r(\tau) = \int \sqrt{\left({E\over m}\right)^2 - \left(1-{2M\over r}\right)\left(1+ \left({l\over r}\right)^2\right)}\space\space d\tau + K $$

Where

$$ {E\over m} = \sqrt{1-\left({2M\over r}\right)} \space \gamma_0 $$

$$ l = r^2_0 \left( {d\phi\over d\tau}\right) $$

But I have absolutely no idea how to integrate this, as there are terms on the RHS that contain $r$.

I apologise if this is an elementary question, but I haven't done much of this.

PS. I realise this question may seem better suited to physics.SE, but my question is purely from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: You can use `\left(...\right)` (or `\bigl(...\bigr)`, `\Bigl(...\Bigr)`, etc.) to make correctly-sized parentheses, as well as other delimiters.

Comment: Simple integration will not work. This is a non-linear differential equation.

Comment: I suppose $\,r=r(\tau)\;$ is a function of $\,\tau\;$ , or perhaps $\,M, l, \;or\;\;E\,$ are... right? Otherwise this is a trivial integral.

Comment: @ZettaSuro I thought as much. Would you know how I should go about integrating it?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, $r = r(\tau)$, $M$ is constant, $E$ and $l$ are also dependent on $r$.

Comment: Oh, dear! Then @user912, this is far from being trivial and pretty close to be nightmarish...I'm not sure whether a definite answer, whether by means of elementary or not functions, can be given in the general case unless (perhaps...maybe not even then!) the actual functions are known...

Comment: Yes, as DonAntonio said, the solution will be heavily dependent on $M(r)$, $E(r)$, and $l(r)$. And depending on what they are, there may not even be any closed form solution.

Comment: @ZettaSuro See my edit, I've added some equations for $E$ and $l$. $M$ is constant.

Comment: Is it not more typical to solve for the orbits as a function of the angular variable phi rather than as a function of the proper time? As on way I typically see this done is the problem is integrated for selected values of the angular momentum and energy these results are all plotted simultaneously

Comment: I have done integrals like this to determine time for a particle to fall radially inward from any distance,  the integrand just being the reciprocal of the one you've given

Comment: @Dan I would rather get the equations with respect to $\tau$

Comment: I had to do these integrals using maple..I'm unsure if there is any way to do them otherwise, and I also had to choose special cases for values of the angular momentum and energy